# swig import local shared library in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, shared-libraries, static-libraries, swig

I have built my library in the `lib/` folder within my `swig` folder, because I need the shared library (`.so`) to be there in the package without building it at install. 
Without any modifications to `swig_import_helper` I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/MyProject/swig_wrapper.py", line 6, in <module>
    import swig_decoders
  File "/MyProject/swig/swig_decoders.py", line 26, in <module>
    _swig_decoders = swig_import_helper()
  File "/MyProject/swig/swig_decoders.py", line 25, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_swig_decoders')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_swig_decoders'
```

I have thereforre modified `importlib` in order load the local library:

```py
def swig_import_helper():
        import importlib
        pkg = __name__.rpartition('.')[0]
        mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_swig_decoders')).lstrip('.')
        try:
            return importlib.import_module(mname)
        except ImportError:
            try:
                import os
                import importlib.util
                BASE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
                spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module._swig_decoders", os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'lib'))
                foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
                spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
            except:
                return importlib.import_module('_swig_decoders')
    _swig_decoders = swig_import_helper()
```

the libraries are located in the local path `swig/lib`:

```
MyProject/swig/lib/swig_decoders-1.1-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/
EGG-INFO                    _swig_decoders.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  swig_decoders.py
__pycache__                 _swig_decoders.py
```

but I'm still getting an import error now:

```
  File "MyProject/swig/swig_decoders.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_swig_decoders'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyProject/swig/swig_decoders.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Is this due to a library path error or to the importlib when using `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location`?

**strong text**

Comment: So which file did you modify? *swig\_import\_helper* appears to be in *swig\_decoders.py*, but you mentioned *importlib*. Also which are files created by you and which ones are auto generated? Also, **why  do you have *\_swig\_decoders.py***?

Comment: @CristiFati so I can see a `_swig_decoders.py` auto-generated file in the library EGG.